# Copying first lines of multiple text files into single file

Tags: bash, unix, text-files

Using single bash command (pipes, stdio allowed)
copy first line of each file whose name begins with ABC to file named DEF.

Example:

Input:

ABC0:

```
qwe\n
rty\n
uio\n
```

ABC1:

```
asd\n
fgh\n
jkl\n
```

ABC2:

```
zxc\n
bvn\n
m,.\n
```

Result:

DEF:

```
qwe\n
asd\n
zxc\n
```

Already tried `cat ABC* | head -n1` but it takes only first line from first file, others are omitted.

Comment: `Using single bash command (pipes, stdio allowed) copy first line of each file whose name begins with ABC to file named DEF.` - this is homework, right?

Comment: Look like home-work indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want `head -n1 ABC*` to let `head` take the first line from each file. Reading from standard input, `head` know nothing about where its input comes from.

`head`, though, adds its own header to identify which file each line comes from, so use `awk` instead:

```
awk 'FNR == 1 {print}' ./ABC* > DEF
```

`FNR` is the variable containing the line number of the current line of the input, reset to 0 each time a new file is opened. Using `./ABC*` instead of `ABC*` guards against filenames containing an `=` (which `awk` handles specially if the part before `=` is a valid `awk` variable name. HT William Pursell.)

Comment: Note that this will have trouble with files containing an `=` in the name.

Comment: Or `awk 'FNR == 1 {print; nextfile}' ABC*` to avoid processing more than 1-line per file.

Comment: `nextfile` isn't standard, but good to use if available. I'm trying to think of a better fix for the `=`-containing filenames than running `head -n1` on each file separately.

Comment: "For many years, `nextfile` was a common extension. In September 2012, it was accepted for inclusion into the POSIX standard. See [the Austin Group website](http://austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=607)" -- from [GNU Awk User's Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Nextfile-Statement.html#Nextfile-Statement)

Comment: Heh. Any idea when the next version of POSIX is actually going to be released? :) But as the link notes, most major versions do support it.

Comment: No guess on when, yours is better than mine `:)` I was just happy to learn it was actually included.

Comment: `awk 'FNR == 1' ./ABC*` gets around the issue of `=` in the names.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the file names don't contain spaces or newlines, and that there are no directories with names starting with `ABC`:

```
ls ABC* | xargs -n 1 head -n 1
```

The `-n 1` ensures that `head` receives only one name at a time.

If the aforementioned conditions are not met, use a loop like chepner suggested, but explicitly guard against directory entries which are not plain files, to avoid error messages issued by `head`.

Comment: Basically no, that's why I stated the prerequisites for this to work; but the alternative would be to do a `echo ABC*|fmt -w 1` instead, and this would not be any better.

Comment: No, the alternative is to not use `xargs` in the first place.

Comment: @chepner: If you *know* for sure, how your file names look like, my solution is an alternative. That's why I placed the warnings in my answer, saying explicitly that if the prerequisites are not met, a loop needs to be used. Of course if the preconditions don't hold, it is in programming always _garbage in, garbage out_.